# How Can I Specify an Allocator at Comptime in Zig?

Tags: compile-time, allocator, zig

In Zig, I want specify an allocator at `comptime` in order to remove the added overhead of passing around an allocator to each function that requires it. In the following MWE, I have a type generator that takes in a `comptime` `ArenaAllocator` and returns a type with that allocator as a "static" member. The type is instantiated, called `MyType`, and then an object of `MyType` is initialized using the previously specified allocator.

```rust
const std = @import("std");

fn MyTypeGen(comptime arena: *std.heap.ArenaAllocator) type {
    return struct {
        var allocator = arena.allocator();

        data: []const u8,

        pub fn init(data: []const u8) !@This() {
            const temp = try allocator.alloc(u8, data.len);
            @memcpy(temp, data);

            return .{ .data = temp };
        }
    };
}

pub fn main() !void {
    comptime var arena = std.heap.ArenaAllocator.init(std.heap.page_allocator);
    defer arena.deinit();

    const MyType = MyTypeGen(&arena);

    const val = try MyType.init(&[_]u8{ 1, 2, 3 });

    std.debug.print("{}\n", .{val});
}
```

The problem is **the above code fails with a segmenation fault**:

```rust
Segmentation fault at address 0x7ff63e46b628
C:\Program Files\zig\lib\std\heap\arena_allocator.zig:171:39: 0x7ff63e3f2788 in createNode (Calculator.exe.obj)
        self.state.buffer_list.prepend(buf_node);
                                      ^
C:\Program Files\zig\lib\std\heap\arena_allocator.zig:184:29: 0x7ff63e3f216a in alloc (Calculator.exe.obj)
            (self.createNode(0, n + ptr_align) orelse return null);
                            ^
C:\Program Files\zig\lib\std\mem\Allocator.zig:225:53: 0x7ff63e4242dd in allocBytesWithAlignment__anon_6797 (Calculator.exe.obj)
    const byte_ptr = self.rawAlloc(byte_count, log2a(alignment), return_address) orelse return Error.OutOfMemory;
                                                    ^
C:\Program Files\zig\lib\std\mem\Allocator.zig:211:40: 0x7ff63e3f2e37 in allocWithSizeAndAlignment__anon_3321 (Calculator.exe.obj)
    return self.allocBytesWithAlignment(alignment, byte_count, return_address);
                                       ^
C:\Program Files\zig\lib\std\mem\Allocator.zig:129:41: 0x7ff63e3f11f3 in alloc__anon_3262 (Calculator.exe.obj)
    return self.allocAdvancedWithRetAddr(T, null, n, @returnAddress());
                                        ^
C:\...\src\main.zig:10:45: 0x7ff63e3f1044 in init (Calculator.exe.obj)
            const temp = try allocator.alloc(u8, data.len);
                                            ^
C:\...\src\main.zig:24:32: 0x7ff63e3f1486 in main (Program.exe.obj)
    const val = try MyType.init(&[_]u8{ 1, 2, 3 });
                               ^
C:\Program Files\zig\lib\std\start.zig:348:65: 0x7ff63e3f175c in WinStartup (Program.exe.obj)
    std.os.windows.kernel32.ExitProcess(initEventLoopAndCallMain());
                                                                ^
???:?:?: 0x7ffee8867343 in ??? (KERNEL32.DLL)
???:?:?: 0x7ffeea8426b0 in ??? (ntdll.dll)
run Program: error: the following command exited with error code 3:
C:\...\zig-out\bin\Program.exe
Build Summary: 3/5 steps succeeded; 1 failed (disable with --summary none)
run transitive failure
+- run Program failure
error: the following build command failed with exit code 1:
C:\...\zig-cache\o\03618dc1d07de7a2b7ce2381e69121e1\build.exe C:\Program Files\zig\zig.exe C:\... C:\...\zig-cache C:\...\AppData\Local\zig run
```

It appears the issue is that Windows specifies the heap allocator, which backs the `ArenaAllocator`, at runtime meaning that `comptime var arena` is initialized erroneously. Zig must just not be complaining about the ostensibly runtime dependency at compile time, hence the segfault.

**How can I initialize the arena allocator at `comptime` successfully?**

Alternate methods for specifying an allocator at `comptime` which don't require initializing an allocator in the above manner are welcome, too.

Comment: It doesn't really surprise me that you can't initialize an allocator at comptime, but it does seem like the compiler ought to issue an error for that.

Comment: I think there's probably no way to do this with the builtin `Allocator`, but it ought to be possible to specify something that acts like an allocator at comptime (though it'd necessarily be a global singleton).

Comment: This doesn't make sense to me. If you want to remove the overhead of passing an allocator, then use a global allocator. Passing an allocator as a compile-time parameter... what does that give you?

Comment: @sigod In terms of completeness, it doesn't give me anything. But in terms of expressivity, with this syntax I am afforded the ability to express the notion of _ad hoc_ dependent polymorphism (albeit only at `comptime` which is the topic of discussion in my question), which I think looks a lot cleaner than using a global allocator(s).

Comment: @sigod this _is_ about using a global allocator, but it allows the caller to make the decision _which_ global allocator to use. So this would make sense if, say, you were using different allocation strategies on a per-module basis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrapping the allocator in its own global type seems to work.

```
const std = @import("std");

const GlobalArena = struct {
    var global_arena: std.heap.ArenaAllocator = undefined;

    fn init(arena: std.heap.ArenaAllocator) void {
        global_arena = arena;
    }

    fn deinit() void {
        global_arena.deinit();
        global_arena = undefined;
    }

    fn allocator() std.mem.Allocator {
        return global_arena.allocator();
    }
};

fn MyTypeGen(comptime GlobalAllocator: type) type {
    return struct {
        var allocator = GlobalAllocator.allocator();

        data: []const u8,

        pub fn init(data: []const u8) !@This() {
            const temp = try allocator.alloc(u8, data.len);
            @memcpy(temp, data);

            return .{ .data = temp };
        }
    };
}

pub fn main() !void {
    GlobalArena.init(std.heap.ArenaAllocator.init(std.heap.page_allocator));
    defer GlobalArena.deinit();

    const MyType = MyTypeGen(GlobalArena);

    const val = try MyType.init(&[_]u8{ 1, 2, 3 });

    std.debug.print("{}\n", .{val});
}
```

```
$ zig version
0.12.0-dev.587+eb072fa52

$ zig build run
main.MyTypeGen(main.GlobalArena){ .data = { 1, 2, 3 } }
```